# What is the difference between my LLVM IR and Clang's

Tags: c, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

Currently I am working on a programming language that requires me to use LLVM. I am using clang as a reference because it uses LLVM too.

```c
// The C code example I am using
int add(int num1, int num2){
    int result = num1 + num2;
    return result;
}
```

```
; The Clang output from compiling the C example code
define i32 @add(i32 noundef %0, i32 noundef %1) #0 {
  %3 = alloca i32, align 4
  %4 = alloca i32, align 4
  %5 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 %0, i32* %3, align 4
  store i32 %1, i32* %4, align 4
  %6 = load i32, i32* %3, align 4
  %7 = load i32, i32* %4, align 4
  %8 = add nsw i32 %6, %7
  store i32 %8, i32* %5, align 4
  %9 = load i32, i32* %5, align 4
  ret i32 %9
}
```

```
; My own version of the compiled C example code
define i32 @add(i32 %0, i32 %1) #0 {
  %2 = add nsw i32 %0, %1
  ret i32 %2
}
```

This is my version of the llvm ir generation

This is my first time using llvm and I am not sure what are the differences between those two code snippets in terms of speed and safety.

Comment: That looks like unoptimized C codegen, which is super "pedantic" and pretty terrible. Can you get the IR after some optimizer passes?

Comment: Your code looks like it was written by someone who really, really, really, really wants to use variables. "You can write Fortran in any language" as they say. Clang's code looks like stylish IR. There are passes that'll transform your output to be more like clang's, at least this example. I don't know whether those passes will fix *all* code your frontend generates, or whether you should make a mental effort to generate SSA-ish IR, with few or no `alloca` instructions. That's quite a mental effort if you've never used anything other than block-structured languages (no forth, no assembly).

Comment: Try adding a -O flag to clang (O for optimize) - it should give you somewhat similar results to your own IR

Comment: yes, you are right @MortenJensen

Comment: @KostiaIlnytskyi nice! I love being right ;D FWIW I've learned most from reading LLVM IR with -O1 for slightly optimized output :) some of the transformations in -Ofast or -O3 I can't really follow/understand without some research and -O0 (i.e. no optimization) is very verbose. However it usually also maps more 1:1 with C code so YMMV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "address of" operation in LLVM IR, but there is in C.

When clang emits IR, it doesn't scan through variables to check whether it needs to allocate space on the stack for them, instead it always allocates space on the stack (the `alloca` instructions) and uses loads and stores to access the value. If the address is needed, the alloca instruction is the pointer. If the address is never needed, LLVM will clean it up in the optimization phase.

Comment: To add to your answer: [mem2reg](https://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#mem2reg-promote-memory-to-register) is the optimization in this specific case.

Comment: You're right, but note that the optimization named mem2reg isn't run at any -O level in clang, instead the mem-to-reg'ing is done as a part of [SROA](https://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#sroa-scalar-replacement-of-aggregates).